# VirtualBox suddenly stopped working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I've been running VirtualBox 5.2.4 with no problem for months on Ubuntu 16.04.  Today it wouldn't start and recommended running `/sbin/vboxconfig` which failed.  It complained about the permissions on the file /dev/vboxdrv, which didn't exist.

I removed virtualbox and downloaded and installed the latest version (5.2.14) using the Ubuntu Software Installer.  It still fails to start.  I removed it using the Software Installer.

If I run `sudo dpkg -l | grep virtualbox`  it shows virtualbox packages still exist.  I run `sudo apt-get remove virtualbox` but it shows nothing to remove.  Running `purge` also leaves these files intact:

```
 $ sudo dpkg -l | grep virtualbox
ii  unity-scope-virtualbox                      0.1+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu1                  all          VirtualBox scope for Unity
rc  virtualbox-5.1                              5.1.18-114002~Ubuntu~xenial                  amd64        Oracle VM VirtualBox
rc  virtualbox-5.2                              5.2.14-123301~Ubuntu~xenial                  amd64        Oracle VM VirtualBox
ii  virtualbox-dkms                             5.1.34-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.2                 all          x86 virtualization solution - kernel module sources for dkms
rc  virtualbox-qt                               5.1.34-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.2                 amd64        x86 virtualization solution - Qt based user interface
```

It looks like I've got old virtualbox packages that can't be removed or purged are interfering with a new install.  Or dpkg and apt-get are showing different things.

Is anyone else suddenly having problems running VirtualBox on Ubuntu 16?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution presented [here](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=84990) worked.  Purge all virtualbox packages -- especially unity-scope-virtualbox -- and then install the latest .deb package from Oracle.  These were the steps I took:

```
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-5.1
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-5.2
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-qt
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-dkms
sudo apt-get purge unity-scope-virtualbox

sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-5.2_5.2.14-123301_Ubuntu_xenial_amd64.deb
```

Be sure to install from the command line.  I don't trust Ubuntu's Software Manager any longer.

Comment: Please make an answer that details the steps that you took. It helps preserve the answer in case the link becomes dead in the future.